# How to calculate S3 Costs

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm wondering if I'm calculating S3 costs correctly.

Let's say I have a huge file 100 Gbs, and a GET request for that data is executed 100 times per month.

For the HTTP request, I've got a penny $0.01 for under 10,000 requests.
Then for the storage, I'm getting $0.023 per GB or $2.30 for 100 Gigs.

So my monthly costs at this rate will be $2.31? Si?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are **mostly correct**, with a few assumptions:

- Your bucket is located in `us-east-1`, `us-east-2` or `us-west-2` (at the time of writing this Answer)
- You do not have the [Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) (which can give you some free usage)
- You do not have other expenditure in your account (which could qualify you for lower rates due to volume discounts)

The one cost you have excluded is **Data Transfer Pricing**, which will apply if the file is being downloaded *to the Internet*. The price is 9c/GB in those regions. This price does not apply if the file is being accessed within the same AWS region (eg from an Amazon EC2 instance in the same region). Also, the first 1GB of Data Transfer is free each month.

Therefore, if the 100GB file is being downloaded 100 times to the Internet (100 x 100GB = 10TB) , the cost of Data Transfer (excluded the first free 1GB) would be: `100 x 100 x 9c = $900`

Comment: Woah! That last part sounds important, and dwarfs the other costs. So if I host a static site on S3, and say I put oh, 100gigs of video there, and 100 different people watch those videos, then I'm paying $900?

Comment: Yes. 100 GB of video would be 150-200 hours of video. If 100 people download it, then it is 10TB and 20,000 hours of video. About 5c/hour but it adds up when you have hundreds of videos and hundreds of viewers.